# Replacing integers of all columns of a pandas dataframe with True/False

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I've got a pandas data frame with integers.

I want to replace 1 with `True` and 2 with `False` for all columns in my data frame , so to make a data frame with booleans only.

I thought I'd try to loop over all of the columns using something like `df[Col] = df[Col].astype(bool)`, but when I tried it out on `Col1` it just replaced every value in `Col1` with `True` when it should be `True`, `True`, `False`, `True`.

Thanks for any help!

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [1,1,2,1],
        'Col2': [2,2,1,1],
        'Col3': [1,1,1,2],
        'Col4': [2,1,2,2]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
df == 1
```

Output:

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0   True  False   True  False
1   True  False   True   True
2  False   True   True  False
3   True   True  False  False
```

Comment: Your answers never fail to suprise me. +1

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks.  I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [1,1,2,1],
        'Col2': [2,2,1,1],
        'Col3': [1,1,1,2],
        'Col4': [2,1,2,2]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
df = df.replace(1,True)
df = df.replace(2,False)
df
```

Output:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0   True    False   True    False
1   True    False   True    True
2   False   True    True    False
3   True    True    False   False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.replace`.

```
df.replace([1,2],[True,False])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
>>> df == 1                      
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0   True  False   True  False
1   True  False   True   True
2  False   True   True  False
3   True   True  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the context of integers, `.astype(bool)` changes all non-zero integers to True, and all zeros to False. I would use `map` as follows:

`df[Col] = df[Col].map({1:True, 2:False})`